# What Certificate Store do you place certs in to be spread across the Domain

Tags: windows, certificate, active-directory, domain

Good Morning guys,

As the title mentions, I have a collection of .p7b files for Root, Intermediate, and untrusted certificates. I just don't know what store (or does it have to be group policy) to have them placed in so that it will populate into those same stores across the domain.

We're working with W2K22 and the Windows AD-Domain services.

*If it is a Group Policy thing, is it possible to script that (I know I can script GPO creation, I just don't know about the certificate part) or is it a matter of telling a Group policy to look at those 3 stores on the primary DC?

Thanks in advance for any assistance/guidance

Answer (score 1):

You may use a Group Policy for it, as described in the
Microsoft article
[Distribute Certificates to Client Computers by Using Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/distribute-certificates-to-client-computers-by-using-group-policy).

This is done in the Group Policy Management snap-in,
as described in the linked article.

Each new policy can be be associated with any number of certificates
and one certificate store.